How can a code work on dev but fails on production?
This code works perfectly fine on my dev-replit:
 `transition_music_segment = AudioSegment.from_file(temp_file_name, format="mp3")

But it gives an error on production:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Here's full traceback:
2024-10-04 21:13:35,487 - root - ERROR - Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.../audio_generator.py", line 393, in generate_tts_concurrently
    transition_music_segment = AudioSegment.from_file(temp_file_name, format="mp3")
  File "/home/runner/.../pydub/audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
  File "/home/runner/.../pydub/utils.py", line 279, in mediainfo_json
    info = json.loads(output)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Any ideas why this could happen, and why on production-replit only?
Please note that this code has been working for many months without any issues, I just made a small code update yesterday, pushed to production and since than I've been getting this error.

For those experiencing a similar issue: I had to create a new Repl from scratch, which has up-to-date packages both on dev and prod (in the previous setup prod version of ffmpeg and fprobe was "unknown"). It solved the issue. I got almost no support from Replit team, so I wouldn't rely on them helping you with critical issues.


json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Your json decoder doesn't like the data it is reading.  Start by verifying you are reading the file you think you are reading and that it contains the data you think it contains.

Thanks. This service retrieves an mp3 file from an external service (google storage), and it works well on development server.
A similar code piece that retrieves a speech file from Elevenlabs creates the same issue:
audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_file(temp_audio_file.name,
format="mp3")
Meaning, it works well on dev, but fails on prod.
These are different services (Google & Elevenlabs), they both work well on dev, but they fail on prod. I believe there is "something" missing on prod but not sure what.
